# Safari ios when submiting form from https to http the page start loading but it stops

Tags: php, ios, forms, http, safari

When I try to submit a form from Https to http it shows:

> Form Insecure are you sure you want to submit?

when I submit the page, it starts loading and it hangs forever. This form submitting works on android PC and safari mac.

Comment: this is a simple fix. If you have any instances of `http://`, change them all to simply `//`. This for href's, images, scripts, etc.

Comment: your method worked but it redirected to https:// instead of http:// and it gave me page not found im using code igniter

Comment: *"When i try to submit a form from Https to https"* - I don't get this (edit: ok, you edited).  Now you say it redirects to https. You're going to have to check if you have a header/redirect somewhere or in `.htaccess`. The question is unclear in regards to that. If you want to redirect to http, use a header or other form of redirection to be http instead.

Comment: Just do a redirection, see what I posted in the answer below. If that still doesn't work, you will need to post your code and other relevant information that I/others can use and hopefully provide you with a complete solution. I have to note that I may not be able to help you with CodeIgniter since I haven't worked with it enough and I do not work with that framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in comments, change all instances of `http://` to `//` for scripts, images, etc. they will automatically detect either protocol for the environment it's in.

If as you say it redirects to an `https` protocol rather than what you would like it to redirect to `http`, you can simply use a [header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) or other form of redirection.

Examples:

```
header("Location: http://example.com/other_page.php");
exit; // This stops further execution
```

or a meta method:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=finalpage.html">
```

or Javacript:

```
window.location.replace("http://example.com/");
```

The above examples were pulled/borrowed from:

[How to make a redirect in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-to-make-a-redirect-in-php)